# Using modern Java HTTP client to Tomcat 9; cannot get HTTPS to work though self-signed certs in place

Tags: java, https, java-9, keytool, tomcat9

Tomcat configured for both 8080 and 8443:

> ```
> <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>            connectionTimeout="20000"
>            redirectPort="8443" />
> <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>         connectionTimeout="20000"
>         scheme="https"
>         secure="true"
>         SSLEnabled="true">
>     <SSLHostConfig>
>         <Certificate certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"
>                 certificateKeystoreFile="certificates/tomcat.jks"
>                 certificateKeystorePassword="changeit"
>                 truststoreFile="certificates/tomcat.jks"
>                 truststorePassword="changeit" />
>     </SSLHostConfig>
> </Connector>
> ```

This code works:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri( new URI( "http://localhost:8080/application/" ) )
        .headers( "Content-Type", "application/xml" )
        .headers( "Accept", "application/xml" )
        .POST( HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString( PAYLOAD ) )
        .build();
HttpResponse< String > response = client.send( request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString() );
```

while the HTTPS code fails with IOException: PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri( new URI( "https://localhost:8443/application/" ) )
        .headers( "Content-Type", "application/xml" )
        .headers( "Accept", "application/xml" )
        .POST( HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString( PAYLOAD ) )
        .build();

HttpResponse< String > response = client.send( request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString() );
```

...despite running JVM with:

> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyPassword=changeit 
> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/tomcat/certificates/tomcat.jks 
> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit 
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/tomcat/certificates/trust.jks 
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit

Here's how I built the certificate artifacts:

```
$ keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -validity 365 -keystore tomcat.jks -dname "cn=windofkeltia.com"
$ keytool -export -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt -keystore tomcat.jks-storepass changeit
$ openssl genrsa -out trust.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key trust.key -out trust.crt -subj "/CN=windofkeltia.com/"
$ keytool -importcert -alias tomcat -file trust.crt -keystore trust.jks -storePass changeit
# ll
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat  863 Jul 28 11:32 tomcat.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat 2697 Jul 28 11:31 tomcat.jks
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat 1314 Jul 28 15:26 trust.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 tomcat tomcat 1287 Jul 28 15:26 trust.jks
-rw-------  1 tomcat tomcat 1679 Jul 28 15:26 trust.key
```

Comment: Did you include the self-signed CA (Certificate Authority) certificate?

Comment: @JimGarrison (Sorry, I was unavoidably gone for 2 days) I added how the certificates were built.

Comment: It's been a while since I did any of this, but your process doesn't look right.  You generated your self-signed certificate OK, but I don't see where you used it to sign your Tomcat server certificate.  Also, when you connect, doesn't the host name need to match the CN in the certificate?